# Replacing arbitrary fields in Kubernetes YAML

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to use `configMap` variables inside my Kubernetes YAML outside of my container specification.

Basically, I am looking for a way to replace text in my configuration with the value of a configMap entry due to me having almost the same resources in multiple namespaces.

For example, imagine the following `configMap`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config
data:
  system.host: host.example.com
```

Then, I want to use the values of this `configMap` inside of other resources, e.g. an `HttpRoute`:

```yaml
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: my-system-route
spec:
  parentRefs:
  - name: my-gateway
    namespace: my-gateway-namespace
  hostnames:
    # I would imagine something along the lines of this
  - ${config/my-config/system.host}
  rules:
  - matches:
    - path:
        value: /
    backendRefs:
    - name: my-backend-service
      port: 8080
      kind: Service
```

and get `${config/my-config/system.host}` replaced with `host.example.com`.

Ideally, I want Kubernetes to replace that and not using other CLI tools as I want it to be possible to apply the configuration from different systems/OSes.